# How can I check my SSD lifespan?

Tags: windows-8, ssd, windows-8.1

How can I check the lifespan of my SSD? Is there a built-in feature on Windows 8?

If not, what could I do to check it?

Comment: This is incorrect. There's a SMART parameter, SSD Life Left. Is it perfect? Certainly not, but it's generally a reasonable estimate.

Comment: Its an estimate. There is no accurate way to know the answer.

Comment: When is such information not an estimate? The lifetime for almost every piece of hardware is only estimated. I think the goal isn't to know the accurate lifetime but a approximate value to know the general health.

Answer (score 1):

I always used CrystalDiskInfo for precise Information. And SSDlife to view the health of it. 
I may not tell you acurately the lifespan but for example how many dead cells are on your SSD.

If you have a Samsung SSD there is also Samsung Magician Tool.

Answer (score 0):

You can try [smartmontools](http://en.netpower.fr/smartmontools-win) for windows.

Or you can run any Linux Live CD/USB and install [smartmontools](http://www.smartmontools.org/) in it.

[image]

[image]